# httpClient 200 response but empty body?

Tags: c#, rest, jira, response, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using httpClient to access a url which has json data for Jira. I have tested accessing the page and HttpResponseMessage returns a 200 code.

When I go directly to the url and login that also resolves the content.

However when I attempt to read the response body I don't get anything as it's empty. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong! I am really stuck so any help would be appreciated!

Initial attempt at the bottom - I have also removed .Result and tried just using a GetStringAsync response like this, but had no joy - response2 is still empty :(

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{token}")));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result; 


        var response2 = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);


        //Checking that the response is returning a 200
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            resultsTest.InnerHtml += "Success :)" + response.ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            resultsTest.InnerHtml += "Failed :( ";
        }
```

Initial Code prior to changes made due to the comments below: 
I've attempted to read the response body in three different ways (labelled in the comments!):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testAsync();
    }

    protected async System.Threading.Tasks.Task testAsync()
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        //var confString = "https://myUrl.co.uk/rest/api/content?expand=body.view&limit=500&start=1&type=page";
        var uriString = "https://myUrl.co.uk/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=RES&fields=key,summary&maxResults=1000&startAt=0";
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);

        var username = "bob";
        var token = "bob";

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{token}")));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result; 

        //First attempt to read content body
        string res = "";
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            // ... Read the string.
            Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            res = result.Result;
            resultsTest.InnerHtml += "------";
            resultsTest.InnerHtml += res;

        }

        //Second attempt to get the body to return as a string: 
        var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        resultsTest.InnerHtml += contents.ToString();

        //Third attempt to get the body of the response
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            // ... Read the string.
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // ... Display the result.
            if (result != null &&
                result.Length >= 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 50) + "...");
                resultsTest.InnerHtml += "*************"; 
            }
        }




        //Checking that the response is returning a 200
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            resultsTest.InnerHtml += "Success :)" + response.ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            resultsTest.InnerHtml += "Failed :( ";
        }

    }
```

Comment: When you say empty you mean empty string `""`? Does the code execute past the blocking call made at `HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result; `

Comment: Noticed the mixing of async-await and blocking calls like `.Result` that can cause deadlocks.

Comment: You are already using `async`. You should not be using `.Result`.

Comment: Why dont you use `.GetStringAsync()` on `HttpClient`, that way you don't have an extra object you have to traverse.

Comment: @nkosi yes it does execute past that point :)

Comment: @trailmix I've tried taking out the async and using just the .Result and vice versa - they don't bring anything back by themselves either :(

Comment: @hlh3406 The point hes making is that youre using an async method thus you shouldn't access the result via `.Result', you should await the async method or face deadlocks. There is no vice versa.

Comment: @hlh3406 if you dont want to await you can workaround like `.GetStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` But your `testAsync()` method is already async so..

Comment: @KieranDevlin agh ok my mistake sorry! Do you know how I can access the results using async instead of .Response?

Comment: @hlh3406 `var response = await client.GetStringAsync(...);`

Comment: @KieranDevlin I've tried that and removed all the .Response but still don't get anywhere... :( Have updated the post to show this :)

Comment: Apparently you're still using `GetAsync` over `GetStringAsync`
`HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;`.

Comment: At this point I would suggest you use a listener like fiddler and review the raw request and response being returned form the URL.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct [**SecurityProtocolType**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netframework-4.8)?